# How do I add one day or 12 hours to date in format of Thu Mar 03 2022 12:00:00 GMT in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I want to add one day or 12 hours to a date in the format of

```
Thu Mar 03 2022 12:00:00 GMT
```

I have tried:

```
new Date(value.startDate + 1);
```

but it does nothing.

Please help me out, I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+add+one+day+to+date+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: _one day or 12 hours_? Which do you want?

Comment: @mplungjan 12 hours

Comment: `let d=new Date(value.startDate); d.setHours(d.getHours()+12)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const date = new Date("Thu Mar 03 2022 12:00:00 GMT");

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add something to your timestamp, this will do the trick no matter what you want to add.

```js
const timestamp = new Date("Thu Mar 03 2022 12:00:00 GMT")
console.log(timestamp.toString())

// because getTime and setTime uses milliseconds:
const millisecondsToBeAdded = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000
timestamp.setTime(timestamp.getTime() + millisecondsToBeAdded)

console.log(timestamp.toString())
```